# Check-In to SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

Can someone tell me how to check-in a file to SharePoint after its uploaded using a Web Service? Is there an option that can be changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Lists.CheckInFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkinfile%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as long as you perform this operation as the same user who uploaded the document, which is luckily your scenario. See also some [community code samples](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/8d8ab053-205e-49c2-a811-92c55925ca4e).

If you want to change this behaviour, [remove the check-out requirement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/configure-a-site-library-to-require-check-out-of-files-HA101853114.aspx#_Toc270603902) from your document library.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully upload of a file in Sharepoint document library , you have to write code for the prgramatically checkin , publish and approve the document

use [`[Lists.CheckInFile]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkinfile%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

method for this purpose